# How to estimate customer utilization of AWS Glue and Athena

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-athena, aws-glue

Does anyone know how to get monthly breakdowns of costs per Glue Data Catalog and Athena Querying?

I have several customers (each with own data catalogs) and want to charge them separately. Can’t find documentation to do so, and tags are not implemented for this services yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Glues pricing is $0.44 per DPU-Hour, billed per second, with a 10-minute minimum for each ETL job and Athena pricing is $5 per TB of data scanned. Glue provides the first 1m stored and requests in a data catalog and then $1 per 100,000 objects stored above 1M, per month
stored and 1 per million requests above 1M in a month

Comment: Thanks @ChuckLaPress, I’m wondering how to breakdown costs across internal customers, think cost centers. I know some AWS services allow for cost allocation tags, but that doesn’t seem to be the case with Glue and Athena.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read completely your original question looking at the most current services that provide cost allocating tagging, your right Glue and Athena are not listed as available services. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/custom-tags.html#allocation-how This reportedly has been updated and current as of 09/18/18